# How to change Vector Objects into different colours?

Tags: c++, vector, colors

I've been trying to get my code to change vectors objects into different colours. I've put an example of two of the methods I've used for vectors and getting colours. Does anyone have any information on how to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

std::vector<std::string> playerInventory;

int main() {

    HANDLE color = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); //just once
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(color, 10);
    std::cout << "This";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(color, 11);
    std::cout << " is";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(color, 12);
    std::cout << " a";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(color, 13);
    std::cout << " colour";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(color, 14);
    std::cout << " combination" << std::endl;

    playerInventory.push_back("1");
    playerInventory.push_back("2");
    playerInventory.push_back("3");
    playerInventory.push_back("4");

    for (int x = 0; x != playerInventory.size(); ++x)
    {
        std::cout << playerInventory[x] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to already know how to change the colors, so what you need to do is just change the color inside your loop, for each element of the vector. Example:

```
for ( int x = 0; x != playerInventory.size(); ++x ) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( color, 10 + x );
    std::cout << playerInventory[x] << std::endl;
}
```

Keep in mind though, that there's only so many valid values from [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`'s `wAttribute` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#_win32_font_attributes)

Comment: Thank you! That's really useful. If I wanted to say have a two worded vector object, such as: "playerInventory.push_back("Hello There");", how would I go about making the first word one colour and the second another colour?

Comment: @Oxic, you would need to split the string by word, and do the same sort of thing. There's many examples on SO about splitting strings you can have a look at.